# Python : Basemap barbs , wind vector plotting on map

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plotting wind vector on map using basemap.barbs.

I try to draw it as a test with simple code.

No error message is shown with this code, Even if I wait, the picture does not come out..

If a picture is being drawn, the picture does not come out even after waiting a long time.

I think there seems to be something else wrong.

It is the first time to draw a wind field with Python, so I'm immature.

Is it because of the high data resolution? (Its len(lon) is 360, len(lat) is 200)

Or is it another matter?

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,addcyclic,shiftgrid

data=nc.Dataset('wind.nc','r')

lon=data.variables['XU_OCEAN'][:]
lat=data.variables['YU_OCEAN'][:]
time=data.variables['TIME1'][:]
uwind=data.variables['WIND_POWER_U'][:]
vwind=data.variables['WIND_POWER_V'][:]

uwind_DJF=[]
vwind_DJF=[]
for i in range(11,20*12+1,12):
    uwind_DJF.append((uwind[i]+uwind[i+1]+uwind[i+2])/3)
    vwind_DJF.append((vwind[i]+vwind[i+1]+vwind[i+2])/3)

uwind_DJF=np.mean(uwind_DJF,axis=0) ##shape is (200,360)
vwind_DJF=np.mean(vwind_DJF,axis=0) ##shape is (200,360)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
m=Basemap(resolution='l',projection='cyl',llcrnrlon=-90,llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlon=80,urcrnrlat=70)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,1,0],fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,45),labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
lon2d,lat2d=np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y=m(lon2d,lat2d)
m.barbs(x,y,uwind_DJF,vwind_DJF)
plt.show()
```